# How to use selenium to access web database in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, selenium-webdriver, django-models

I am running a Django website using the given dev server command

```
./manage.py runserver
```

The website contains a submission form with the textfield "title" and a submit button. Once the button is clicked, the input is saved as an object in the Titles table initialized by the following Django model:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

I am testing on Python to see if the input is actually saved as an object in the table by using django.test.TestCase and selenium webdriver to write a title and click submit. The problem is that I don't know how to access the objects in the datatable afterwards. Is there a way to access the datatables on the servers using a test method?

I am using sqllite for the database.

Comment: might be related: https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture i've seen it used for the case you're trying to handle as far as selenium goes it'll be a  `get` to a url, which can be created via `reverse` if it's a named url